# Command to know the Java information about the running process in solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

I want to know the java information that is running for one particular service by their pid in solaris box. Can any one suggest me the command to see the java information for that running process?
I tried using jinfo, but it gives the command not found?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do 'which java' and see if that is found, otherwise $JAVA_HOME/bin may not be in your classpath which is why jinfo may not be found.

Comment: What kind of information ?